# Not able to run TestNG class due to duplicate json-schema-validator

Tags: java, maven, testng, json-schema-validator

I have started writing basic webservices testing using TestNG with Java. By following a tutorial, I have configured the pom.xml and build the project. But, I'm not able to run my TestNG class.

In My Maven Dependency library I'm seeing two json-schema-validator jars - 2.2.6 and 2.9.0.

Please let me know where I'm doing mistake.

POM:

[image]

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Hi, I was not able to add xml format in my requested description. So, I have created an image for it and posted. I'm seeing error notification for the xml format while submitting the question.

Comment: @Prabhakarkpt Can you atleast include the xml in [gist](https://gist.github.com) and share the link by editing your question and adding it there? Also please clarify what error you are getting. Right now there's not much info for us to be able to tie this problem to TestNG in anyway.